# firebase realtime database configuring with firebase functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google

i want to configure firebase realtime databse, with my firebase cloud function.

```
   1)what is "serviceAccountKey.json"?
   2) How to get this file?
   3) did one "serviceAccountKey.json" is enough for all the users using firebase functions?
```

suppose if i use below sample

```
"exports.dbCreate = functions.database.ref('/path').onCreate((event) => {
  const createdData = event.data.val(); // data that was created
   });"
```

how to call dbCreate and what path i have to give in "/path"?
how to get serviceAccountKey.json?

i am using the versions " "actions-on-google" :"^2.0.1",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.12.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.1",
    "dialogflow": "^0.1.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.4.1","

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Functions are server-side (cloud based) scripts that interact with your Firebase project. So, they need a key since they have full access to your project.

Your example `functions.database.ref('/path').onCreate` is not something you call, it is triggered.

Get started with

> a service account to communicate with the Firebase service, and a
>   configuration file with your service account's credentials.
>
> 1. If you don't already have a Firebase project, add one in the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/). The Add
>      project dialog also gives you the option to add Firebase to an
>      existing Google Cloud Platform project.
> 2. Navigate to the [Service Accounts](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk)
>      tab in your project's settings page.
> 3. Click the Generate New Private Key button at the bottom of the Firebase Admin SDK section of the Service Accounts tab.